# Getting scala.MatchError while trying to execute join on Spark SQL query

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have a query that I am trying to execute via spark sql. When I executed the table results separately, I could see results. But when I join them, i am getting scalaMatch error

**Query that I used:**

```py
query = '''
    WITH
      a1 AS (
         SELECT val_in_min, val_date
           FROM table1
      ),
      a2 AS (
         SELECT val_in_sec, val_date
           FROM table2
      )
    SELECT a.val_in_min, a.val_date, b.val_in_sec
      FROM a1 a
      JOIN a2 b
        ON a.val_date=b.val_date
'''
spark.sql(query).show()
```

- **Sample Table1 values**:

```
|val_date  |val_in_min |
|----------|-----------|
|2023-05-01|   11.4833 |
|2023-05-02|   9.90000 |
```

- **Sample Table2 values**:

```
|val_date  |val_in_sec |
|----------|-----------|
|2023-05-01|   23      |
|2023-05-02|   26      |
```

- **Error message**:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o120.showString.
: scala.MatchError: list#77341 [] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ListQuery)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.SizeBasedJoinReorder$.hasFilterPredicate(SizeBasedJoinReorder.scala:285)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.exists$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:92)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:89)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/appcache/application_1686133156822_0013/container_1686133156822_0013_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 441, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/appcache/application_1686133156822_0013/container_1686133156822_0013_01_000001/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/appcache/application_1686133156822_0013/container_1686133156822_0013_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/appcache/application_1686133156822_0013/container_1686133156822_0013_01_000001/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o120.showString.
: scala.MatchError: list#77341 [] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ListQuery)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.SizeBasedJoinReorder$.hasFilterPredicate(SizeBasedJoinReorder.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.SizeBasedJoinReorder$.$anonfun$hasFilterPredicate$1(SizeBasedJoinReorder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.SizeBasedJoinReorder$.$anonfun$hasFilterPredicate$1$adapted(SizeBasedJoinReorder.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:95)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.exists$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:92)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:89)
```

I tried changing the join tables, but am still receiving this error. Please advise what I can change in the Spark SQL to fix this error.

Spark version is 3.0.1 running **on Amazon AWS**.

Comment: Is this the complete error message? Seems to be missing some info.

Comment: I just created two `CSV`s (**table1.csv**, **table2.csv**) in my local, using `spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(table1)` (same for table2), registered as temporal view with `table1DF.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")` and then run your query with `spark.sql(query).show()` and I got two rows. Could you provide more details about what you are doing?

Comment: do you need the `WITH` clause for some reason? or this is just a reduced example of what you are really doing? in this case you are just creating a temporary result set of both tables without any projection, filtering or something else

Comment: @GastónSchabas - I am trying to show only parts of the actual complete code. The SQL has other parts and other CTEs that builds up table1 a1 and table2 a2. When I do select * from a1 or a2, and when I try to do a df.show(), I could see the data which would look like the table values shown in my question

Comment: @GaëlJ - Added more error log. Faced character limit issue previously

Comment: @GastónSchabas - In the actual dataset, table1 will have 7 rows and table2 will have 7 rows. the final res table will be a join between table1 and table2 on date column to fetch minutes and seconds values for that date. I couldn't paste the complete SQL as it has business logic. Had to reduce the example

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/MatchError.html) - `This class implements errors which are thrown whenever an object doesn't match any pattern of a pattern matching expression`.

Comment: @Andrew - Does this mean the dates aren't matching? The data types of the dates in table1 and table2 are the same and both tables have dates.

Comment: you tagged the post with `scala`, but your error log looks like python error messages. Are you using apache spark? pyspark? is your code written in python? please share a bit more about the stack used, how the project is being built and executed, and use the correct tags if the ones are not correct

Comment: @GastónSchabas - Apologies. I am executing this on Jupyter Hub on EMR using Pyspark. Since I saw Scala on the error message, I thought this could be related to Scala.

Comment: Yes. `scala.MatchError` is an error from `scala`. It occurs when you are trying to do [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) and there is no `case` that match with that object. I tried to reproduce your case using scala and I didn't succeed. Not sure if the root cause comes from scala or python. That's why I'm suggesting to add more context such as the stack used, how you build the app, the command you used to execute it and else. we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you

Comment: @GastónSchabas - Thanks for explaining. This is not fully developed into an app yet. I am trying to execute the sql through Jupyter Hub that runs on EMR using Pyspark to execute the spark SQL. That's when I faced this error.

Comment: Can you try setting `spark.sql.optimizer.sizeBasedJoinReorder.enabled` to `false` and see if it succeeds?

Comment: @mazaneicha - Tried setting this ```%%configure -f
{ "conf" : { "spark.sql.optimizer.sizeBasedJoinReorder.enabled": "false"}}```..  Received error message ```Invalid status code '400' from http://Xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/sessions with error payload: "Unrecognized field \"spark.sql.optimizer.sizeBasedJoinReorder.enabled\" (class org.apache.livy.server.interactive.CreateInteractiveRequest), not marked as ignorable

Comment: Well... perhaps you can do `spark.sparkContext.getConf().set("spark.sql.optimizer.sizeBasedJoinReorder.enabled", False)` ?  I don't use AWS, and based my comment solely on this amazon article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-performance.html.

Comment: Besides, I haven't seen any traces of `SizeBasedJoinReorder.scala` (referenced in your stacktrace) in upstream Spark v.3.0.1 https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v3.0.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer

Comment: @mazaneicha I couldn't find it even if I use the [search bar of github](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aapache%2Fspark%20SizeBasedJoinReorder&type=code). The closest thing with that name, was a test suite named [SizeBasedJoinReorderSuite](https://github.com/SaurabhChawla100/spark-radiant/blob/a13368e68433d4625e39e9546d38bc7f0b61fd22/spark-radiant-sql/src/test/scala/com/spark/radiant/sql/catalyst/optimizer/SizeBasedJoinReorderSuite.scala#L34)

Comment: @mazaneicha - I added this to spark configuration and it worked. ```"spark.sql.optimizer.sizeBasedJoinReorder.enabled" : "false"``` Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Guess this AWS feature isn't ready for prime time yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `"spark.sql.optimizer.sizeBasedJoinReorder.enabled": "false"` as part of Spark configuration, as @mazaneicha recommended, and the spark sql worked. Thanks for your help

**Documentation:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-performance.html

Comment: This looks like a genuine bug. Perhaps you can refer it to AWS.

Comment: I second what @mazaneicha says. Fixing the error just by changing the value to a property, doesn't seem like an expected behavior.